# matplotlib x-axis formatting if x-axis is pandas index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using iPython notebook's %matplotlib inline and I'm having trouble formatting my plot.

[image: Plot that needs x-axis formatting]

As you can see, my first and last data point aren't showing up the way the other data points are showing up. I'd like to have the error bars visible and have the graph be "zoomed out" a bit.

```
df.plot(yerr=df['std dev'],color='b', ecolor='r') 

    plt.title('SpO2 Mean with Std Dev')
    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
    plt.ylabel(SpO2)
```

I assume I have to use

```
matplotlib.pyplot.xlim()
```

but I'm not sure how to use it properly if my x-axis is a DataFrame index composed of strings:

```
index = ['-3:0','0:3','3:6','6:9','9:12','12:15','15:18','18:21','21:24']
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: How about `plt.xlim(-1, len(index))`?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the usage of xlim [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim). Basically in this case if you ran `plt.xlim()` you would get`(0.0, 8.0)`. As you have an index that uses text and not numbers the values for xlim are actually just the index of the entries in your index. So in this case you would just need to change the values by feeding in however many steps left and right you want your graph to take. For example:

```
plt.xlim(-1,len(df))
```

Would change this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Hope that helps.